# Python not opening text files when they are in the same directory as script

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a file in python. Simple enough. The script that I am using is the same directory as my code, so I just use

```
myfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
```

This worked fine before, but now I am getting the error 'No such file or directory' (Errno2)

Why is this happening? I've used OS to check if I am in the right directory, and it is fine. What is python doing differently now than it did 20 minutes ago, when it found the file perfectly??

Comment: Could you copy/paste from the command line `ls -la` to show the files and permissions, and the command and output for launching your app?

Comment: I added the ls. To launch the app I open the Driver file and input the filename. In this case that is the test1 file, and I also need the .ptt file. Neither of them can be found..

Comment: None of your files have read permissions, across owner, group or other.

Comment: Changing the permissions did nothing. It can't even find the damn files in the first place...

Comment: Use `open('./file.txt','r')`

Comment: In that folder, launch python, type `f = open('test1.fna.txt', 'r')` and paste the result

Comment: @PeterGibson tried that, opened fine, no errors

Comment: Check the filename in your code, you probably have "test1.fna" without the ".txt" on the end

Comment: @PeterGibson wow. 2 hours of my life for that. Thank you.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Happens to the everyone at some point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file you are trying to open/read has appropriate permissions, the behavior is defined based on how you are invoking your python program. Let's assume your code and the `file.txt` are in `~/Desktop`

If you are in `~/Desktop` and do a `python code.py` your code will work fine. But if you are in say your home folder - `~` and do a `python ~/Desktop/code.py` then the python interpreter assumes your current working directory to be `~` and will return the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

since it will not find `file.txt` in `~`

Further, in the context of the given example:

```
os.getcwd()
```

returns the absolute path of your home directory and

```
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

returns the absolute path of your python source file

Comment: But I am in the same folder as both.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you are typing the name wrong, eg "test.fna" versus "test.fna.txt"?

Comment: I think it's because I used Cygwin to use ls. I don't know how to do an ls from the command line in windows :( And I guess since Cygwin is an emulator it doesn't get permissions on my windows files. That was dumb, only confusing people now.

EDIT: Got rid of the ls, if you can tell me how to do the equivalent from cmd that'd be great.

Comment: @PavelVaysberg okay Cygwin explains the permissions issue. Could you paste a SSCCE http://www.sscce.org/ (the source, invocation and output) to demonstrate your problem?